# Nothing happening after get JSON request

Tags: php, jquery, rest

I am calling an API to return some data. I can see in dev tools the response is 200 successful, and in the network tab can see the returned data.

The problem I have is with displaying the data in my UI. At this stage all I want to do is display the returned data in an alert.

I have tried the following, but the alert doesn't fire. I can't see any errors in console, and if I visit the PHP file manually (substituting in the GET variables) there are no errors.

**jQuery**

```
$.getJSON('fetch.php', { getFiat: fiat, getCoin: coin, getLimit: limit, getAggregate: aggregate, getCall: 4 }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
}).fail(function (j, t, e) {
   console.log(e);
});
```

PHP

```
if($_GET['getCall'] == 4) {
    try {
        callAPI();
        $data = file_get_contents('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histoday?fsym='.$_GET['getCoin'].'&tsym='.$_GET['getFiat'].'&limit='.$_GET['getLimit'].'&aggregate='.$_GET['getAggregate'].'&e=CCCAGG&api_key=[key]');
        $json = json_decode($data);

        if(isset($json->Response) != "Error") {
            echo $data;
        } else {
            echo "Broken duh..";
        }
    }

    //catch exception
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The API response looks like this: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=30&aggregate=1&e=CCCAGG

Comment: Did you verify if the return JSON data is valid? `getJSON` might fail silently if data is invalid.

Comment: `if(isset($json->Response) != "Error") {` is wrong but not sure if that's the cause of the issue (invalid json?). `isset` returns a boolean so should ever equal "Error". That line should probably be `if(isset($json->Response) && $ison->Response != "Error")`

Comment: I tried to add a further check to see if getJSON is failing (edited example above) and in console it says: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 12046` and points to the `console.log(e)` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This checks `isset` which returns `true` or `false` and then checks if that `true` or `false` NOT equal to `"Error"`:

```
    if(isset($json->Response) != "Error") {
```

If it `isset` then it returns `true` which is `==` to `"Error"`.  You need two separate checks.  Depending on what is returned in case of error, maybe:

```
    if(isset($json->Response) && $json->Response != "Error") {
```

Or check for success:

```
    if(isset($json->Response) && $json->Response == "Success") {
```

Comment: This is sensible advice, but isn't related to my specific issue. Up-voted nonetheless.

Comment: You may have other issues, but with your current code the `echo` will never execute.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital Why isn't this related? It's clearly not going into the branch you wanted because `isset()` will never match "Error"

Comment: I made a mistake - I tested this and it didn't work but it was because I tried on the wrong environment.. Thanks for the help.